# How to wake up APP from sleeping (ActionScript 3 - AIR for Android)

Tags: android, actionscript, air

I use Flex SDK + ActionScript 3.0 to develop APP for Android.

I need a function to wake up my APP when OS is sleeping.
For example, an alarm clock, it counts time in background and "wake up" to ring the bell when specific time matches.
I need the same action to "wake up" my APP from sleeping. I did some google search like "Native Extension" or "NativeProcess class" but it seems can't afford my goal.

I need some suggestion.
anyone ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you will need an ANE (Adobe Native Extension). There are loads out there by now.
this is one of them -> [onglongfei/ANE-ALARM-Service](https://github.com/donglongfei/ANE-ALARM-Service)